# flash php chatting site

Tags: php, flash

I want to know if someone can give me some good tutorials links on how should i make a flash chatting site having all the basic chatting features. Also i would like to get a how-to for sharing files like its done in msn messenger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check

http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/flash_chat/index.php

HTH.